# Linq To Sql - Dynamic OrderBy - Case When

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic, sql-order-by

I'm using **Linq to sql** and **Linq Dynamic** OrderBy.

I know linq dynamic can do simple sorting like - **orderby("column_name").**

But **does it support something more complex like queries with "CASE WHEN" in them ?**

```
string orderbyQuery = "(CASE WHEN (username == 100) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC)";
```

here is my query :

```
var u = from u in db.users
        orderby(orderbyQuery)
        select u;
```

the above example doesn't work! , any idea if its possible?
any other way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
var u = from u in db.users
        orderby u.username == 100 ? 1 : 0 descending
        select u;
```

Comment: i have to use dynamic query because ,
i have a int[] realUsers = 100, 22 , 77 , 12 , etc...
i want to sort Users table based on that int[], meaning show the users in "realUsers" first.

Comment: You can replace that u.username == 100 ? 1 : 0 with (almost) any logic you want for ordering, you're essentially just writing it in C# instead of Sql. Without knowing exactly how you're trying to order it's hard to give a better example than converting your original code...

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Cat 
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public Cat(string name) { Name = name; }
}    

var cats = new List<Cat> { new Cat("cat1"), new Cat("cat2"), new Cat("cat3") };
var customSortExpression = new List<string> { "cat2", "cat1", "cat3" }.CustomSortOrder<Cat>("Name");

//custom sort order, works with EF too //orders cat2,cat1,cat3               
var customOrderCats = cats.AsQueryable().OrderBy(customSortExpression);
```

when used with EF, this generates sql like the following

```
SELECT [c].[Name]
   FROM [Cats] AS [c]
   ORDER BY CASE
       WHEN [c].[Name] = N'cat2'
       THEN 0 ELSE CASE
           WHEN [c].[Name] = N'cat1'
           THEN 1 ELSE CASE
               WHEN [c].[Name] = N'cat3'
               THEN 2 ELSE 3
           END
       END
    END
```

Here is my extension method `CustomSortOrder<TEntity>`.

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> CustomSortOrder<TEntity>(this IList<string> customSortOrderValues, string propName) {

var e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
var prop = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var eDotProp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(e, prop);
var maxLen = customSortOrderValues.Count;

Expression ElseExpression(IList<string> values) {
    var value = values[0];
    var condition = Expression.Equal(eDotProp, Expression.Constant(value));
    var ifTrue = Expression.Constant(maxLen - values.Count);
    Expression ifFalse ;

    if (values.Count == 1) {
        ifFalse = Expression.Constant(maxLen - values.Count + 1);
    }
    else {
        values.RemoveAt(0);
        ifFalse = ElseExpression(values);
    }
    return Expression.Condition(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse);
}

return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, int>>(
    ElseExpression(customSortOrderValues),
        e);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make linq to sql create a single CASE statement and not lots of nested ones like that? I have a large case statement which, when nested, goes over the nesting limit and so the sql fails. Or is this just a bug in linq with no work around?

Comment: I dont think you should do this solution if the number of cases are very high. this is a stop gap solution when you want to combine the order from another source than the table source and very limited number of caess.

Comment: This works great for dynamic GROUP BY; I modified it slightly to take a list of date ranges as continuous periods and then grouped by the period number with a sum of the values for each period coming from the one round-trip. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

This really works for me:

```
var queryResult = 
   from o in Source
   orderby (o.ColumnThatSaysOrderByColumn1 ? o.Column1 : o.Column2) descending
   select o
```

Hope this helps!