# Custom sort logic in OrderBy using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

What would be the right way to sort a list of strings where I want items starting with an underscore '_', to be at the bottom of the list, otherwise everything is alphabetical.

Right now I'm doing something like this,

```
autoList.OrderBy(a => a.StartsWith("_") ? "ZZZZZZ"+a : a )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013198/linq-to-sql-dynamic-orderby-case-when/56868434#56868434

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you want custom ordering, but don't want to supply a comparer, you can have it - sql style:

```
autoList
.OrderBy(a => a.StartsWith("_") ? 2 : 1 )
.ThenBy(a => a);
```

Comment: I like this solution better. I always forget about ThenBy.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to use [`OrderBy(Func<>, IComparer<>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) and specify your own [`Comparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zzyats9.aspx) which will implement your custom logic .

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload of OrderBy that takes an `IComparer`, the first `Func` argument will feed the comparer, and from there you need to compare the strings. First deal with the case of one or both starts with `_`, and then from there you will probably need to strip the `_` and just use the standard `string.Compare` to sort them beyond the first `_`

Comment: However, in all honesty, although technically your approach is a hack and can fail, it's a lot simpler and easier to understand your intent.