# Linq Ordering by Merged Columns

Tags: .net, linq, sql-order-by

I need to Order and Page a Linq query, but it should be made by ordering a custom column like this: 
If my entity Person was an employee, it's name come from the table Employee, if not it'll come from the table Person, and these differ. For that I've a field that return it's name, appling this rule, so i need to order by the name, and then page the query.

The Problem:
Doing this way, all the tables data need be loaded to do this ordering, and paging, something like 100.000 rows to get 10. I want to this ordering work in DB, before loading my 10 rows in EF.

Is there any way to implement in my query an order by with an "IF" clause, leaving the work with the DB and loading only my 10 rows page?

Maybe something like this:

`persons.OrderBy(p => (p.Employee != null)? p.Employee.Name : p.Name).Take(10);`

Comment: Dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want...

Comment: Uhh... you just posted the solution yourself?! What's the question, then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007470/custom-sort-logic-in-orderby-using-linq  also, ternary will be translated into CASE WHEN in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
persons.Select(p => new { Emp = (p.Employee!=null) ? p.Employee.Name : p.Name})
       .OrderBy(p => p.Emp)
       .Take(10);
```