# How can I use lazy loading logic of pagination to retrieve FileSystem kind of hierarchichal data

Tags: c#, linq, logic

I have a table Asset storing the files and folders data in it having the ParentDirectoryID referencing to the parent directory of any item. Now in UI The items are displayed as below -

Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
File1
File2

But in database they can be store in any order like -

File1
Folder1
File2
Folder2
Folder3
File3

Now I want to enable paging to the data displayed on UI, but the Issue I am facing is how can I fetch the first X number of records having folders first and files later sorted by the Name.

Edit:-
AssetType is as follows - 
 Folder
 ImageFile
 TextFile
 Assembly etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `OrderBy()` extension method to first order on asset type (folder / other), and `.ThenBy()` filename.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, hwever there not only 2 asset types, asset type also differentiate files like image file, text file etc.. and I do not want to sort files by type instead they should be sorted by NAme only

Comment: @Harshal you need to have an identifier that tells whether something is a folder. You can then do something like `.OrderBy(f => f.IsFolder).ThenBy(f => f.Filename)`.

Comment: And this IsFolder can not be in the code right? As per my knowledge if I write the C# Function or extension method then it won't be accepted by LINQ...

Comment: @Harshal you have to translate the 'IsFolder' to your own logic.

Comment: Which is not possible i think, because thats the main issue here, even if I have own logic of IsFolder where to write it? Do you mean adding a field in the database which tells whether asset is folder or not? but even if we change DB that would not be good design as AssetType is already saying that it is folder.

Comment: @Harshal of course it is possible. Replace 'f.IsFolder' with 'f.AssetType == "folder"'...

Comment: but in that case it would sort all the items by AssetType, and i do not want the Files to be sorted by ItemType... as there would be different type of files having assettype like image file, text file, dll file etc...

Comment: @Harshal come on man, try something yourself, I'm not going to spell out the code for you. You first have to `.OrderBy()` by asset type, where you assign "folder" assets a value of 0 and other assets a value of 1 (see [this question if you do not understand this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007470/)). This way, the folders will be on the top. After that, you order `.ThenBy()` the name of the asset. This will work, I've used it plenty of times before, ken also suggests it so don't say it won't or update your question with what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i was under the impression that the ".ThenBy" would actually sort it something simillar to how SQL sorts the items e.g. select * from employee order by departmentid, name.    Here it would sort the items with department id and would sort the items within one department by NAme... thats why i thought it would not work, but as you are saying its working for you.. let me try.. Thansk once again

Comment: @Harshal stop assuming, start coding. Actually that is exactly how `.ThenBy()` works and that is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks will try it without assumption this time.. :)

Comment: It worked I used below statement to do it -  folderContent.OrderBy(a => a.AssetType > 0 ? 1 : 0).ThenByDescending(e => e.Name)

Comment: @Harshal nice! Happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ThenBy` clause to get a second ordering from the database.

```
var source = query
    .OrderBy(item => item.FolderOrFile)
    .ThenBy(item => item.Name);
var pagedItems = source
    .Skip(itemsPerPage * requestedPage)
    .Take(itemsPerPage);
```

I've got a [project](https://code.google.com/p/source-pagination/) (on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Pagination.Mvc/)) that takes care of some of this functionality for you.

Comment: Thanks KEn, I will quickly go through the project and get back to you, however I can not use item.FolderORFile, as there is noflag that would differente just two of these however AssetType would differente two files as well, I metnioned it in the Edits

Comment: Hi Ken, I have just gone through your project, but I am not able to relate it to my problem..

Comment: Sorry Ken, you were right.. I think ThenBy should work in my case too.. giving it a try ..