# Moving an item where there are multiple matches to the top of a list

Tags: c#

I have a list which can contain multiple records of people:

```
 result =people.Select(p => new PersonDetail
            {
                Involvement =  p._Discriminator,
                FullName = p.BuildFullName(),
                DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth != null ? p.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty,
                Race = MappingExtensions.MergeCodeAndText(p.RaceCode, p.RaceText),
                Sex = MappingExtensions.MergeCodeAndText(p.SexCode, p.SexText),
                Height = p.Height,
                Weight = p.Weight != null ? p.Weight.ToString() : string.Empty,
                EyeColor = MappingExtensions.MergeCodeAndText(p.EyeColorCode, p.EyeColorText),
                HairColor = MappingExtensions.MergeCodeAndText(p.HairColor1Code, p.HairColor1Text),
                //...
            }).ToList();
```

I want to order this list by Involvement type (victim, suspect, witness).

I've tried the following using `Remove` and `Insert`:

```
foreach (var i in result.Where(i => i.Involvement.ToLower() =="suspect"))
            {
                result.Remove(i);
                result.Insert(0, i);
            }
            return result;
```

On the first loop it works as I would expect however on the second loop I get an exception thrown. I suspect there is some recursion going on or the exception is thrown because it keeps finding the record I promoted on the first pass and can't get by it.

I wanted to perform a loop vs just one pass as there might be multiple records that are marked as suspect. I need to promote all of these to the top above witness or victims. The other involvements are not relevant in ordering.

example:

```
Bob "suspect"
Jane"suspect"
Kenny "witness"
Joe "victim"
```

Any suggestions on how to select multiple records and ensure they are placed at the top of the list above others?

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions

Comment: You can use OrderBy method of linq. There is an answer here which shows how to sort by custom logic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007470/custom-sort-logic-in-orderby-using-linq

Comment: @AbdullahNehir changing the colleciton type to IOrderedEnumerable and updating the code to return result.OrderBy(i => i.Involvement.ToLower() == "suspect"); does not change the ordering of the items in the list.

Comment: Set the orderby result to your result list. An answer has just come which shows what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your can't change result collection in foreach. The collection used in foreach is immutable and here is MSDN link with explanation: [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

You can use OrderBy to reorder your collection:

```
    result = result.OrderBy(r => r.Involvement.ToLower() =="suspect" ? 0 : 1).ToList();
```

Expression in OrderBy will promote "suspect" items to the top of the result.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer will only succeed if the list being ordered only cares about the precedence of `Suspect` being at the top of the list, i.e.,

```
Kenny, Witness
Bob, Suspect
Joe, Victim
Jane, Suspect
```

In other words, if the ordering precedence also includes `Witness` and `Victim`, the the accepted answer will be correct because Witness is already taking precedence in the order over Victim; when using the accepted answer, the result will correctly be:

```
Bob, Suspect
Jane, Suspect
Kenny, Witness
Joe, Victim
```

However, if the ordering precedence must include strings other than "Suspect", then the accepted answer will fail, i.e. if the list comes in as,

```
Jill, Victim
Kenny, Witness
Bob, Suspect
Joe, Victim
Jane, Suspect
```

Then the result will be:

```
Bob, Suspect
Jane, Suspect
Jill, Victim
Kenny, Witness
Joe, Victim
```

But, the correct result should be (assuming Witness takes precedence over Victim):

```
Bob, Suspect
Jane, Suspect
Kenny, Witness
Jill, Victim
Joe, Victim
```

To custom sort based on a non-alpha sort, you'll need to provide some type of [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar:

```
// Sample class with a name and involvement:
public class Detail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Involvement { get; set; }

    public Detail( string name, string involvement )
    {
        Name = name;
        Involvement = involvement;
    }
}

// implementation of IComparer that uses a custom alpha sort:
public class DetailComparer : IComparer<Detail>
{
    static readonly List<string> Ordered = new List<string> { "suspect", "witness", "victim" };
    public int Compare( Detail x, Detail y )
    {
        int i = Ordered.FindIndex( str => str.Equals( x.Involvement, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) );
        int j = Ordered.FindIndex( str => str.Equals( y.Involvement, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) );

        if( i > j ) return 1;
        if( i < j ) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The list can then be sorted by providing the comparer:

```
var details = new List<Detail>
{
    new Detail("Jill", "Victim"),
    new Detail("Kenny", "Witness"),
    new Detail("Bob", "Suspect"),
    new Detail("Joe", "Victim"),
    new Detail("Jane", "Suspect"),
};

details.Sort( new DetailComparer() );
```

By providing the custom IComparer, any precedence can be declared for every "Involvement".

Comment: Thank you for the information. The current implementation does not require the sorting of additional involvements. They only cared about suspects. This is a nice alternative though and great reference.