# Custom OrderBy on a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to figure out the best way to custom sort a List. Lets say that T is a Object with a date(DateTime?) property and a status(string) property.

I have 3 cases...

"Urgent": I want these at the top of the list, no particular order
date = null
status = "Urgent"

"Normal": I want these ordered by date after the Urgent cases
date = any valid date/time
status = "On Time"

"Later": I want these at the bottom of the list, no particular order
date = null
status = "Later"

Any thoughts? Should I use an IQuerable object instead of List? I can always .ToList() the object later to send to my view.

Comment: From my understanding, its the Object's job to handle sorting by implementing IComparable

Comment: This is another way with Expressions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013198/linq-to-sql-dynamic-orderby-case-when/56868434#56868434

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shouldn't be too difficult, just make `T` implement [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) using your comparison rules and you should be set.

Comment: I'm still messing around with this. This takes .OrderBy() out of the picture, correct?. If I go this route I'd now call list.Sort(). Just so that's clear for future readers.

Comment: @BZink Well you should also be able to do `... myCollection.OrderBy(o => o);` which will order your objects using the default comparer for the object which should be your implementation of `IComparable` however I don't see any advantage to using this over the `Sort()` method.

Answer (score 71):

```
query = query.OrderBy(x =>
  x.Status == "Urgent" ? 1:
  x.Status == "Normal" ? 2:
  3)
  .ThenBy(x => 
  x.Status == "Urgent" ? null:
  x.Status == "Normal" ? x.Date:
  null);
```

Random musing: Does Ordering belong to the query, or to the class?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an extension method:

Something like this...

```
public static IOrderedEmumerable<MyType> OrderForDisplay (this IEnumerable<MyType> input)
{
  return
    input
    .OrderBy(item => item.Status)
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.Status == 1 ? DateTime.MaxDate : item.date);
}
```

Comment: Why would one implement its own extension method for something like that? There are better ways, see the other answers.

Comment: Because it can be reused in other places in the code (if needed) and would make it consistent ordering.
var MyItemsToDisplay = MyList.OrderForDisplay(); (etc...)

Comment: The status is in a string so the orderby would result in a different order than requested. only Normal items should be sorted by date and your code wouldn't compile since there's no method name

Comment: implementing `IComparable` would achieve the same goal. But with a standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide an implementation of IComparer, and then you can pass it in using the following overload:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in my opinion is to use linq :

```
itemsList = itemsList.OrderByDescending(ob => ob.status ).ThenBy(ob => ob.date).ToList();
```