# How to sort List using custom column values in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

Net core, Ef core and linq. I have table with column status. It holds the values New,  In-Progress and closed. When I will query all the rows with New should come first followed by in-progress and closed. Below is my code.

```
var Requests = await this.RequestRepository.GetAsync(x => x.IsActive == true && x.CreatedBy == LoggedInUser, null, x => x.Country).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Below is my GetAsync method

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet;
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

So I am expecting all the rows with status New should come first then In-Progress and closed. I am not finding anyway to figure it out. Can someone help me to write this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable`, so what's stopping you from using the [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) method from LINQ?

Comment: Hi, I need order New, InProgress and closed, so how can i do this?

Comment: An adapted version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278286/9363973) answer should work. Although EF will most probably switch to client side evaluation for this (the difference between client and server side evaluation is explained in detail [here](https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-evaluation-client-server))

Comment: Add the definition of the New/Inprog/Closed enum to your question

Comment: You're passing `null` for `orderBy` so why would you expect the results to be ordered?

Comment: I'm not really sure what having this "helper" method gives you over just having straight up LINQ - why do you use it? Save a few keystrokes at the expense of making your code readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your life would probably be a lot easier if you throw this "helper" method away and just use LINQ straight. Look how much more obviously readable it is:

```
var apps = db.FundingApplications
  .Include(x => x.Applicant)
  .Where(x => x.ApplicationDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
  .OrderBy(x => (int)x.Status)
```

(I skipped the await/async for brevity, not because I'm advocating sync)

Status of course being an enum like:

```
enum Status{
  New, Inprogress, Closed
}
```

If your enum is awkwardly NOT in numeric order like this but is instead eg

```
enum Status {
  New = 20,
  InProgress = 1,
  Closed = 99
}
```

Then you could order it by descending after you ToString it (you'll notice the names are in reverse alphabet order) or create a mapping using a dictionary that maps eg `d[New] = 0, d[InProgress] = 1 ...`, or do an (in-line) if set in the OrderBy.

```
OrderByDescending(x => x.Status.ToString("g"));

var d = new Dictionary<status, int>() {
  {New, 0}, {InProg,1}, {Closed,2}
};
OrderBy(x => d[x.Status]);

OrderBy(x => x.Status == Status.New ? 0 : (x.Status == Status.InProg ? 1 : 2))
```

Only the last of these has any real chance of being executed on the server though, and ordering by its name will only work If you don't rename them or add new names that break the ordering.

I do also appreciate the OrderBy/ThenBy given in the other answer and think it's good but I think care should be given to testing whether it executed on the server or the client because it carries out a boolean compare and a lot of db don't use booleans as a data type or if they do they might sort falsy (0) ahead of truey (1)

```
OrderBy(x => x.Status == New)
```

Might just be then that it sorts all closed and InProg ahead of New because the result of the boolean if evaluated by the server is 0 for InProg/closed and 1 for new. MySql and Postgres would be my top picks for worrying that this would be server evaluated because they do allow boolean type values in contexts other dbs don't.

So, be careful that a) this kind of ordering is evaluating where you expect and want (client/server) and b) if it really is evaluating on the server that the server orders it as you want

---

Edit, just saw your comment that indicates that Status isn't an enum but some set of string constants??

If your DB values are literally string and status was never an enum then you can just order them by descending

```
OrderByDescending(x => x.Status)
```

Comment: Indeed. And, this way you can use `.ThenBy` and `{OrderBy|ThenBy}Descending` which is lost when using the helper.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but for my this also worked var siteAssessmentRequests = await this.SiteAssessmentRequestRepository.GetAsync(x => x.IsActive == true && x.CreatedBy == LoggedInUser, x =>x.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Status == "New").ThenByDescending(x => x.Status == "In Progress").ThenByDescending(x => x.Status == "Closed"), x => x.Country).ConfigureAwait(false); so which is best fit ? this one or you shared one

Comment: @Niranjangodbole fair enough, I forgot that you were passing a Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` as opposed to an `Expression<Func<T, K>>`. However, as this answer points out, your version is significantly harder to read.

Comment: Er, they kinda have different purposes. I'm saying you should throw it away because 99.9% of LINQ aware developers will just be able to straight pick up my version and read it like a sentence and tell you what it does. If you posted your comment there as a question on SO saying "what does this do" everyone would say "post the definition of GetAsync" because it's just not readable or self documenting. It's not how we use repository pattern either; when we use repositories we give a clear named method like `GetCurrentYearsApplicationsWithApplicantsOrderedByStatus` and do all the LINQ inside it

Comment: What you have there is just some kind of wrapper method that might perform a filter, or an include, or a sort but I don't see what it gives you other than yet another method to remember the definition of in order to make sense of what it does, which is highly contextually driven by its arguments. I'm proposing that you should just straight use the LINQ because you're not saving many(if any) keystrokes and you're making the code harder to read and understand, so hard in fact that you have to come and ask for help to make it go. The next guy who maintains it will probably have to too

Comment: ps; when I said "how we use" I meant our organisation personally, not c# developers as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a sample code according to your requirement. It's working fine on mine. Please refer to this. Hope this will work on your code too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Name> list = new List<Name>
            {
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan1", LastName = "Dhungana1", Status = Status.Closed},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan2", LastName = "Dhungana2", Status = Status.New},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan3", LastName = "Dhungana3", Status = Status.New},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan4", LastName = "Dhungana4", Status = Status.Closed},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan5", LastName = "Dhungana5", Status = Status.Closed},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan6", LastName = "Dhungana6", Status = Status.InProgress},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan7", LastName = "Dhungana7", Status = Status.Closed},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan8", LastName = "Dhungana8", Status = Status.InProgress},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan9", LastName = "Dhungana9", Status = Status.InProgress},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan10", LastName = "Dhungana10", Status = Status.New},
                new Name { FirstName = "Nishan11", LastName = "Dhungana11", Status = Status.New}
            };

            list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Status == Status.New)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Status == Status.InProgress)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Status == Status.Closed)
                .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("hey");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Status
    {
        New = 1,
        InProgress = 2,
        Closed = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working what I need.  just for my info, is it possible to include as part of GetAsync method only? Thanks