# Custom Sorting in Linq to Entities based on QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Spent all day trying to find ready to use solution for "Sort data in LINQ bases on Query String" without any results.

SO, I have a LINQ query in action:

```
public AcrionResult MyAction(int perPage = 10, string orderBy = "DESC", sting sortBy = "id")
{
    var some = from m in db.Some select new ExampleModel {id = m.id, some = m.some};
    return View(some);
}
```

From exmaple above:

1. perPage describe how many items we should show in page
2. orderBy DESC or ASC order
3. sortBy can be some field from ViewModel

I need to make somethisng like this:

var query = some.OrderFilter(...).AmountFilter(...).SortByFilter(...)

Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013198/linq-to-sql-dynamic-orderby-case-when/56868434#56868434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Here's [another example](http://landman-code.blogspot.com/2008/11/linq-to-entities-string-based-dynamic.html) of implementing dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0):

The page size is best handled by [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) and [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) – LINQ to Entities will translate that in to SQL.

The parametrised sort can be done either by creating an expression tree based on the selected property and passing it to [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.orderby.aspx) or [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.orderbydescending.aspx) as needed. Or by using Entity-LINQ building the SQL from the name of the field.

The latter apporoach needs to white-list the column names to avoid SQL Injection..