# LINQ Custom Sort

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want an alphabetic sort with one exception.
There is a Group with a Name = "Public" and an ID = "0" that I want first.
(would rather use ID = 0)
After that then sort the rest by Name.
This does not return public first.

```
public IEnumerable<GroupAuthority> GroupAuthoritysSorted 
{ 
   get 
   { 
       return GroupAuthoritys.OrderBy(x => x.Group.Name); 
   } 
}
```

What I want is:

```
return GroupAuthoritys.Where(x => x.ID == 0)
       UNION 
       GroupAuthoritys.Where(x => x.ID > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Group.Name);
```

GroupAuthority has a public property Group and Group has Public properties ID and Name.

I used basically the accepted answer

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SortCustom
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TestSort();
        }
        private void TestSort()
        {
            List<CustomSort> LCS = new List<CustomSort>();
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(5, "sss"));
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(6, "xxx"));
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(4, "xxx"));
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(3, "aaa"));
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(7, "bbb"));
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(0, "pub"));
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(2, "eee"));
            LCS.Add(new CustomSort(3, "www"));
            foreach (CustomSort cs in LCS) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cs.Name);
            LCS.Sort();
            foreach (CustomSort cs in LCS) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cs.Name);
        }
    }
    public class CustomSort : Object, INotifyPropertyChanged, IComparable<CustomSort>
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
        private Int16 id;
        private string name;
        public Int16 ID { get { return id; } }
        public String Name { get { return name; } }
        public int CompareTo(CustomSort obj)
        {
            if (this.ID == 0) return -1;
            if (obj == null) return 1;
            if (obj is CustomSort)
            {
                CustomSort comp = (CustomSort)obj;
                if (comp.ID == 0) return 1;
                return string.Compare(this.Name, comp.Name, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
            if (obj == null) return false;
            if (!(obj is CustomSort)) return false;
            CustomSort comp = (CustomSort)obj;
            return (comp.ID == this.ID); 
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (Int32)ID;
        }
        public CustomSort(Int16 ID, String Name)
        {
            id = ID;
            name = Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `class GroupAuthority`.

Comment: @ClickRick GroupAuthority has a public property Group and Group had Public properties ID and Name.

Comment: Please edit it into your question.

Comment: GroupAuthoritys.OrderBy(x => x.Group.Name == "Public" && x.Group.ID == 0 ? 0 : 1, x.Group.Name);

Comment: On ny phone, cant remember exactly the syntax, but that is the basic idea of getting it done

Comment: I will test out the answers when I get back from breakfast.  Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013198/linq-to-sql-dynamic-orderby-case-when/56868434#56868434

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a comparison function, they are functions that from two instances of your type return an integer that return 0 if both are equals, a negative value if the first is less than the second and a positive value if the first is greater than the second.

MSDN has a [nice table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3(v=vs.110).aspx) that is easier to follow than text (StackOverflow still doesn't support tables in 2014)

## `IComparer<T>`

Most sort methods accept a custom comparer implementation of type [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) you should create one encapsulating your custom rules for `Group` :

```
class GroupComparer : IComparer<Group>
{
    public int Compare(Group a, Group b)
    {
        if (a != null && b != null && (a.Id == 0 || b.Id == 0))
        {
            if (a.Id == b.Id)
            {
                // Mandatory as some sort algorithms require Compare(a, b) and Compare(b, a) to be consistent
                return 0; 
            }
            return a.Id == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        }

        if (a == null || b == null)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(a, b))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return a == null ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(a.Name, b.Name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
items.OrderBy(_ => _, new GroupAuthorityComparer());
```

## `IComparable<T>`

If it is the only way to compare `Group` instances you should make it implement [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) so that no aditional code is needed if anyone want to sort your class :

```
class Group : IComparable<Group>
{
    ...
    
    public int CompareTo(Group b)
    {
        if (b != null && (Id == 0 || b.Id == 0))
        {
            if (Id == b.Id)
            {
                // Mandatory as some sort algorithms require Compare(a, b) and Compare(b, a) to be consistent
                return 0; 
            }
            return Id == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        }
        
        return Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(Name, b.Name);
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
items.OrderBy(_ => _.Group);
```

The choice between one way or the other should be done depending on where this specific comparer is used: Is it the main ordering for this type of item or just the ordering that should be used in one specific case, for example only in some administrative view.

You can even go one level up and provide an `IComparable<GroupAuthority>` implementation (It's easy once Group implement `IComparable<Group>`):

```
class GroupAuthority : IComparable<GroupAuthority>
{
    ...
    
    public int CompareTo(GroupAuthority b)
    {
        return Comparer<Group>.Default.Compare(Group, b.Group);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
items.OrderBy(_ => _);
```

The advantage of the last one is that it will be used automatically, so code like: `GroupAuthoritys.ToList().Sort()` will do the correct thing out of the box.

Answer (score 10):

You can try something like this

```
list.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    if (x.Id == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (y.Id == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return x.Group.Name.CompareTo(y.Group.Name);
});
```

Where list is `List<T>`.

This method takes advantage of custom sort option provided by `List<T>` using `Comparison<T>` delegate.

Basically what this method does is, it just adds special condition for comparison when `Id`, If it is zero it will return a value indicating the object is smaller which makes the object to come in top of the list. If not, it sorts the object using its `Group.Name` property in ascending order.

Comment: This is getting up votes and I sure wish I could understand it.  Please explain.

Comment: @Blam Added explanation, sorry for delay. It was my time to leave office :(

Comment: I did not vote it down.  I am going to try and test it.

Comment: @Blam Thanks, I tested before posting, if anything let me know I'll look into it.

Comment: This works +1.  Why do you think  -2 on the question?

Comment: does this work if I am using IQueryable instead of in-memory list?

Comment: @shole No. Sort method isn't available on `IQueryable` it's available in `List<T>` only. You need to use `OrderBy` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
    public IEnumerable<GroupAuthority> GroupAuthoritysSorted 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return GroupAuthoritys.OrderBy(x => x.Group.ID == 0)
                                  .ThenBy(x => x.Group.Name); 
        } 
    }
```