# Putting Some Items First in List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am just wondering the best approach to place certain items in a List at the top of the List.  This model is used in a view to display search results and comes from the controller as a `List<T>`.  So My goal is Display all Items , but Items with a certain property will go to the beginning of the list so they are displayed first.

so my controller would be something like :

```
List<Item> listFromRepository = repository.GetSearchResults();
List<Item> topItems = listFromRepository
                            .Where(x => x.Subject == 5)  // any filter for items to be at top of search results
List<Item> listForView = new List<Item>();
listForView.AddRange(topItems);
listForView.AddRange(listFromRepository.Exclude(x => x.Subject == 5));
return Json(listForView);
```

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? What's not working?

Comment: It works , I know SO isn't really the place for optimization questions , but this is just really ugly and long and seems like it's creating an extra object for no reason

Comment: Why not use an order by?

Comment: that is what I wanted , but I don't think OrderBy() allows you to do something like  all Items With SubjectId == 5 go to top and all other SubjectId's go after

Comment: @ScottSelby as someone posted, you can use `OrderByDescending()`.  Unless its more complicated than just an integer?

Comment: arrrggghhh .  Not descending , a specific number , say the user chose 24 , then 24 goes to the top , then every other number goes after

Comment: @ScottSelby ah, you might want to add that to your question

Comment: consider this post, where custom comparing is discussed:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841170/linq-custom-sort

Comment: @ChenR - no , won't work here , that would be overriding the comparrer.  In that question poster always wanted a certain property first .  That is easy , mine is based on user input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this:-

```
List<Item> topItems = listFromRepository.Where(x => x.Subject == 5)
                       .Concat(listFromRepository.Where(x => x.Subject != 5));
```

Comment: holy crap , how are you the only one that knew what I meant , I thought I was pretty clear

Comment: this will work , Haven't tested , but just by loking I know it will be good

Comment: I completely agree, this will work.  But this will iterate the list twice, which is no less than the code you have.  It looks cleaner, but ultimately does the same.  So doubt you will get your performance improvement.

Comment: @Johan - you can't win 'em all , that will do.  you are right about performance ... i think...

Comment: @Johan - Yes, I know it will iterate the list twice, but OP didn't asked a "performance" question, as menttioned by Scott, i just made it from "just really ugly and long" to short. Now, since we can't do ordering, breaking the list and joining is what came in my mind.

Comment: @RahulSingh actually he did mention that he wanted an optimization, but seemed to remove it.  But regardless, your answer is right.

Comment: @Johan , just FYI - I didn't "take out" my request for optimization , click read all comments , everything is there .  I didn't even edit the question, that other guy did

Answer (score 0):

There is also an `OrderBy` function in Linq. In this case you could order by Subject, in descending order.

```
listFromRepository.OrderByDescending(x => x.Subject)
```

Comment: yea , I know , but how do I use this to say place Subject 7 first then all other 1 - 20 after

Comment: Then i suggest you use a weight.

`var items = from i in listFromRepository let weight = GetWeight(i) orderby weight select i;`


With a function to create the weight

    `static int GetWeight(Item i) { return i.Subject == 5 ? 0 : 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
var listForView = listFromRepository.GroupBy(x => x.Subject == 5)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).SelectMany(g => g);
```

I added OrderBy if SelectMany mess with order.
This is neat and faster than other possible queries.

Comment: nah, you would still have to concat what this returned with the other list , this is pretty close to the other selected answer

Comment: The other list is grouped with key of 1 and I think it's ok with SelectMany.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
listFromRepository.OrderBy(x => x.Subject != 4).ToList();
```