# How to sort case insensitive with System.Dynamic.Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I use System.Linq.Dynamic to order an items list.

```
items = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Name ASC");
```

To my surprise, lowercase names gets ordered after the capital cased names, so the items are returned something like this.

```
Ape
Cat
Dog
alligator
ant
beetle
```

I expected this order:

```
alligator
ant
Ape
beetle
Cat
Dog
```

Is there a way to get the correct order? Checked all method signatures for OrderBy and googled around, but nada.

Comment: More in depth answer regarding IComparer/IComparable [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841170/linq-custom-sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a custom comparer, such as:

```
public void Main() 
{   
    String[] words = { "aPPLE", "AbAcUs", "bRaNcH", "BlUeBeRrY", "ClOvEr", "cHeRry" }; 

    var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer()); 

    ObjectDumper.Write(sortedWords); 
} 

public class CaseInsensitiveComparer : IComparer<string> 
{ 
    public int Compare(string x, string y) 
    { 
        return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
    } 
}
```

Found @ https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e

Comment: When I use your more generic example I get it to work. The thing is that I use `AsQueryable` on a `MongoCollection<T>` and then `System.Linq.Dynamic.OrderBy` to try to sort it. When I pass your `CaseInsensitiveComparer` as a second parameter it doesn't work. But that maybe qualifies as another more specific question...

Comment: I used generic sorter but when I passed new CaseInsensitiveComparer() to source.OrderBy<T, object>(sortExpression), it gives me error.

Comment: @Shikha It would help if you provide specific code that you used, which did not work. No offense, but I don't exactly trust what people SAY they did. My gut feel based on your words is that you are not using the overloaded version of `OrderBy()`

Comment: @BryanOfEarth here is the code:
 public IQueryable<T> Sort(IQueryable<T> source, string sortBy, string sortDirection)
        {var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), CollectionName);var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortBy), typeof(object)), param);
            switch (sortDirection.ToLower()){case "asc": return source.OrderBy<T, object>(sortExpression, ); default:return source.OrderByDescending<T, object>(sortExpression);
            }}

Answer (score 11):

You do not need to create a custom comparer because there's already a [`StringComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) class which derives from `IComparer`.

```
words.OrderBy (x => x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

This way, you do not need to create different `IComparer` implementations if you wanted to use other string comparison methods, like `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

However, this might be desirable depending on your situation. For example, I do have multiple extension methods defined in LINQPad, like `OrderBySelfInvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, because it is convenient to use this with code completion rather than typing out the equivalent code by hand:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> OrderBySelfInvariantCultureIgnoreCase(this IEnumerable<string> source)
{   
    return source.OrderBy (x => x, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Using the already-implemented StringComparer classes seems better than the accepted answer, which defines a custom comparer that does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and found no easy solution over the internet. Then I was trying in many ways and finally got a very simple way. It completely worked for me. My solution is

```
string sort = "Name ASC";
string[] data = sort.Split(" ");

items.OrderBy($"{data[0].ToUpper() data[1]}");
```

Now the output is alligator,
ant,
Ape,
beetle,
Cat,
Dog