# Linq sort with Null values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a class with one string  property and it can be null sometimes or it can be a integer number some times or it can be a string .

I want to sort on the basis of this property using LINQ with ascending order of integer values and all nono integer values next and  null values in the end

How can I make a LINQ expression that handles the scenarios

Example

```
"1" ,NULL , "34", "6" ,"67",NULL ,"r45","j34" ,"s"  to be sorted as 

"1" "6" "34"  "67" "j34" "r45" "s" NULL NULL
```

I tried something like this but not really perfect the answer is

```
var licenseitems_master =  my master list 
var firstPart = licenseitems_master.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Page) && x.Page.All(char.IsDigit)).OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Page));
var secondPart = licenseitems_master.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Page) && !x.Page.All(char.IsDigit)).OrderBy(x => x.Page);
var thirdPart = licenseitems_master.Where(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Page)).ToList();
var sorted_items = firstPart.Union(secondPart).Union(thirdPart).ToList();
```

Can we make it as a single LINQ expression?

Comment: You should use your own comparer.
The good explanation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841170/linq-custom-sort

Comment: You have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your class. Then it would be as easy as `var sorted_items = licenseitems_master.OrderBy(x => x.Page).ToList();`

Comment: Why do you have different datatypes in one variable?

Comment: its a client requirement the page can be string sometimes like in example rj45 or simply a number and its not a mandatory field

Comment: @PawełHemperek: Well, not really. Just changing from using `Union` to `Concat` would avoid that code using *any* equality comparisons. A custom comparator is the right way to perform the ordering though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Any help to write a custom comparer

Comment: There's already a link to a question with lots of advice on it. Read that, try to implement it yourself, ask a question if you run into a specific problem with it.

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach in such scenario is to order first by some priority expression, then the rest (which takes effect only for equal priorities) by something else. In your scenario it could be something like this:

```
var sorted_items =
    (from x in licenseitems_master
     let pageOrder = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Page) ? 2 : x.Page.All(char.IsDigit) ? 0 : 1
     orderby pageOrder, pageOrder == 0 ? Convert.ToInt32(x.Page) : 0, x.Page
     select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach with Linq

- first order by ascending  null / not nul
- then order by ascending  the numbers
- then order by ascending

tested with `List<string>`

```
var input = new List<string>() { "1", null, "34", "6", "67", null, "r45", "j34", "s" };
List<string> result = input.OrderBy(x => x == null)
      .ThenBy(x => x != null && x.All(y => char.IsDigit(y)) ? int.Parse(x) : int.MaxValue)
      .ThenBy(x => x).ToList();
```

I would also prefer a custom comparer for that case (which is easier to read / maintain) but the question was about a `Linq` approach

Comment: This is exactly i am looking for . I tried this but the order is not really ascending I am getting result as 1 , 34, 6, 67, j34,r45,null,null . BUt it should be 1,6,34,67,j34,r45,null,null

Comment: @JibinMathew fixed that

Answer (score 2):

You could also go for something like that.

First : TryParse to int, and order by that value (if you can't parse, replace the value by Int32.MaxValue, which will put these values at the end).

Second: put null at end.

Third: Order that result by "string" value

```
int outValue;
var result = input
                .OrderBy(m => Int32.TryParse(m, out outValue)
                    ? outValue
                    : Int32.MaxValue)
                .ThenBy(m => m == null)
                .ThenBy(m => m)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this kind of comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return 0;
        if (x == null) return 1;
        if (y == null) return -1;

        if (x.All(char.IsDigit) && y.All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            var n1 = Convert.ToInt32(x);
            var n2 = Convert.ToInt32(y);
            return n1 - n2;
        }
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var myComparer = new MyComparer();
var sorted_items = "my master list".OrderBy(x => x.Page, myComparer).ToList();
```