# How to sort List by custom Order

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Have some List of Application object
Application has Property  Status and it holds values {"Red",Yellow,Blue ,Green and Orange")

My Requirement is to sort List in custom sort order

"Red" Should come first 
"Blue" Second 
"Yellow" Third
"Green" last

How to implement Sorting in this scenario .
Please help .

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841170/linq-custom-sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Custom Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841170/linq-custom-sort)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could create a list of sorted values and then sort by index in it:

```
var sortedValues = new List<string> {"Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Orange"};
var result = myList.OrderBy(a => sortedValues.IndexOf(a.Status));
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a new class with Id and Name of color property. 
Create an array of the class and order the array by Id.

```
class CutomSort
    {
        class Color
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Name;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Color[] input = {
                                new Color{Id=4, Name="Green"},
                                new Color{Id=3, Name="Yellow"},
                                new Color{ Id=1, Name="Red"},
                                new Color{ Id = 2, Name = "Blue" }
                            };

            IEnumerable<Color> result = input.OrderBy(x => x.Id);

            foreach (Color color in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{color.Id}-{color.Name}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```