# LINQ OrderBy custom order

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the following character array:

```
char[] c = new char[] { 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C' };


c.OrderBy(y => y).ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
//CCCCDDDDDDGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRR
```

How do I use LINQ to produce the following order?

```
//DDDDDDGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRRCCCC
```

Comment: So, what kind of *order* is that?

Comment: How are we meant to guess the ordering rules if you don't tell us?

Comment: @spender the ordering rules are simply "DGRC" not "CDGR"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013198/linq-to-sql-dynamic-orderby-case-when/56868434#56868434 for classes

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
char [] customOrder = { 'D', 'G', 'R', 'C'};
char [] c = new char[] { 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'R',
                         'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R',
                         'C', 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G',
                         'R', 'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C' };

foreach (char item in c.OrderBy(ch => Array.IndexOf(customOrder, ch))) {
    Console.Write(item);
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter he is using ForEach LINQ extension method.

Comment: @Euphoric: there is no `ForEach` extension method apart from one that he might have written from the scratch. http://stackoverflow.com/a/200584/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22System.Collections.Generic.List%601.ForEach%22);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM: that is not an extension method but an instance method of `List<T>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok so you have such thing built-in it's not important an extension or an instance

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM: no, but you have said that it's an extension method and it is not. It was there since .NET 2(so even before LINQ). It's important because OP uses `OrderBy(...).ForEach` and this answer used it also. Using `ToList().ForEach` is a bad habit because you are looping all items in the sequence to create a new collection from the scratch, just to enable to loop it again in `ForEach`. Use `foreach` if you want to loop(consume) a query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter me?? :D are you sure ??

Answer (score 7):

You could use another collection which defines the order:

```
char[] order = {'D','G','R','C'};
var customOrder = c.OrderBy(chr =>
{
    int index = Array.IndexOf(order, chr);
    if (index == -1) return int.MaxValue;
    return index;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to define the order as relation between the items, then you have to use [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.100).aspx) with the other [OrderBy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
public class Comparer : IComparer<char>
{
    public int Compare(Char a, Char b)
    {
       //return positive if a should be higher, return negative if b should be higher
    }
}

c.OrderBy(c => c, new Comparer()).ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Answer (score 4):

My own solution (thank you to those who led me in the right direction)

```
char[] c = new char[] { 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C' };
c.OrderBy(x => "CDRG".IndexOf(x)).ForEach(Console.Write);
```

Produces:

> CCCCDDDDDDRRRRRRRRRRGGGGGG

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary with the order of the elements:

```
Dictionary<char, int> order = new Dictionary<char,int> {
    { 'D', 0 },
    { 'G', 1 },
    { 'R', 2 },
    { 'C', 3 },
};

char[] c = new char[] { 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'C' };

// Here we search the dictionary for the "order" to be used
// and we compare the value with the value of the other 
// compared item
Array.Sort(c, (p, q) => order[p].CompareTo(order[q]));

var str = new string(c);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach this with a join ensuring that the ordering array is on the left side of the join.

```
var ordering = "CDGR".ToCharArray();

var orderedOutput = ordering.Join(c, a => a, b => b, (a, b) => b);
```