# Sort list of strings by another list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of strings that I want to sort by another list of strings and if there are items in the list that is not in the comparer list I want them as they are at the end of the list. How can I do this?

So if I have this list: `List<string> {"A","T","G","F","V","E","W","Q" }`
and I have a comparer: `List<string> {"T","F","V","A" }`
I want the result to be: `List<string> {"T","F","V","A","G","E","W","Q" }`

Thanks!

Comment: So this sort falls back to the original ordering if the string is not in the comparer?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742534/linq-orderby-custom-order

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `Intersect` and `Except` like:

```
List<string> originalList = new List<string> {"A", "T", "G", "F", "V", "E", "W", "Q"};
List<string> compareList = new List<string> {"T", "F", "V", "A"};

var intersectedItems = compareList.Intersect(originalList);
var notIntersectedItems = originalList.Except(compareList);
var resultList = intersectedItems.Concat(notIntersectedItems).ToList();
```

You will get:

```
resultList = T,F,V,A,G,E,W,Q
```

Comment: Will Intersect keep and sort duplicates?

Comment: Intersect and Except, both will remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `List<T>.IndexOf` and use `int.Maxvalue` if it returns `-1`:

```
List<string> result = list.OrderBy(str => {
    int index = comparer.IndexOf(str);
    return index == -1 ? int.MaxValue : index;
}).ToList();
```

Here is a long version which might be more readable for some. It's also more flexible since you can specify what happens with the not-contained items. You could for example order them lexicographically by adding `ThenBy(x => x.String)` before `Select(x => x.String)`:

```
List<string> result = list.Select(str => new
    {
        ComparerIndex = comparer.IndexOf(str),
        String = str
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.ComparerIndex == -1 ? 1 : 0) // not contained -> at the end
    .ThenBy(x => x.ComparerIndex)
    .Select(x => x.String)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var a = new List<string> {"A","T","G","F","V","E","W","Q" };
var b = new List<string> {"T","F","V","A"};

var res = b.Concat(a.Except(b));
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to the others because it is more readable, to me at least. Although the others are very good also.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question asked, this answer gives you all the elements in b but i believe the question is asking for the elements of a that are contained within b to be at the start of the new list.  In other words b could have elements not present in a, and b is just the sorting element

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "A", "T", "G", "F", "V", "E", "W", "Q" };
List<string> input1 = new List<string> { "T", "F", "V", "A" };
var res = input.Union(input1).OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
```