# LINQ OrderBy on the basis of condition

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort List on the basis of CityName such that records with CityName Lahore appears first then Islamabad and then Karachi. 
Below is the source code for reference,

```
class Address {
private City;
}
class City{
private CityName;
}
```

*I am looking for a way to do it with the LINQ OrderBy method.*

Comment: Either write a comparer, or assign each value a sort order and sort on that.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742534/linq-orderby-custom-order/28742588

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried below code, and I believe it has worked.` list.OrderBy(x => x == "Lahore" ? 1 : ( x == "Islamabad" ? 2 : x == "Karachi" ? 3 : 4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> query = cityList.OrderBy(orderedCityList.IndexOf);
```

If a string is not contained in the order-list `IndexOf` returns `-1`so these cities will be first. If you want them to be at the end of the list you can use this query:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = cityList
    .Select(s => new { City = s, Index = orderedCityList.IndexOf(s) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Index >= 0 ? x.Index : int.MaxValue)
    .Select(x => x.City);
```

Comment: What if cityList is part of an object? than I believe it will not be useful.

Comment: @UmairKhan: what do you mean by that? If it's not a `List<string>` but a `List<City>` and the string is actually a property in that class: `cityList.OrderBy(c=> orderedCityList.IndexOf(c.CityName))`

Comment: _What if cityList is part of an object?_ that was not part of the question

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes it is a List<City> and this List<City> is also part of another object. Thus IndexOf method will not be helpful.

Comment: @UmairKhan: well, why you don't ask the right question then? Why you let us find a solution for a non.existing problem? Also, do you want to re-order this single list or is this `City`-object part of another collection that you want to order? Not clear at all.

Comment: @UmairKhan: have you read my comment above? Was this not helpful? `cityList.OrderBy(c=> orderedCityList.IndexOf(c.CityName))`. It's not even cleat what type the list has that you want to order.

Comment: @TimSchmelter First of all thanks for your time. I have updated my question, which shows code structure too. I didn't get the source of orderedCityList. Do you mean that I need to create a separate list first e.g. `List<string> orderedCityList = new List<string>() {
    "Lahore",
    "Islamabad",
    "Karachi",     
  };  `

Comment: @UmairKhan: yes exactly, i thought you had already such a list (or array).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *mapping* (i.e. map actual city name to the desired order):

```
  Dictionary<string, int> order = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    {"Lahore", 1}, 
    {"Islamabad", 2}, 
    {"Karachi", 3},
  };


  ...

  var result = myCollection
    .OrderBy(city => order[city]);
```

In case you have arbitrary cities in the `myCollection` and want first have `Lahore`, `Islamabad`, `Karachi` (in this order) and then all the other cities:

```
  var result = myCollection
    .OrderBy(city => order.TryGetValue(item, out var map) ? map : int.MaxValue)
    .ThenBy(city => city);
```

**Edit**: Why `Dictionary`? Dictionary is efficient in general case, esp. if you have a *long* list of cities. To turn a list into the dictionary:

```
  List<string> cities = new List<string>() {
    "Lahore",
    "Islamabad",
    "Karachi",     
  };  

  Dictionary<string, int> order = cities 
    .Select((value, index) => new {value = value, index = index})    
    .ToDictionary(item => item.value, item => item.index);
```

However, If you have a guarantee that it'll be just few (say, `3`) exceptional cities my solution is an overkill and Tim Schmelter's one is better.

Comment: Why create the dictionary when you can just make a list like Tim suggests?

Comment: @Adrian: If list is *short* (as in the question, just `3` items) Tim's answer is preferrable; however when list is long, Dictionary will be faster.

Comment: Not over kill, or useless. If order change this will be easier to handle on a list large enought. Even when writing the Dict/List this will be easier as you can  seprate the logical order (key order) and the  organizational order (Value order)

Comment: okay if you want to prevent going through the list over and over for larger lists. but then i would suggest you add a code that shows how to turn the list with values into a dictionary for faster lookup