# Sort a List so a specific value ends up on top

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

I have a class `Offer` which contains a filed Category.

I want all Offers of a specific category to appear on top, followed by all else.

I tried this, but to no avail, what would you recommend?

```
Offers = Offers.OrderBy(x => x.Category == "Corporate").ToList();
```

Comment: When you say "to no avail", what's the result of that expression? What's wrong with it?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728319/linq-orderby-against-specific-values

Comment: It doesn't sort properly, it seems to still be in the original order.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you order by a boolean value `false` (0) comes before `true` (1). To get the elements that match the predicate first you should reverse the sort order by using `OrderByDescending`:

```
Offers = Offers.OrderByDescending(x => x.Category == "Corporate").ToList();
```

Comment: Uh, but this will reverse the order of everything else too.  Try `OrderBy(x => x.Category != "Corporate")` instead.

Comment: +1. And perhaps adding a ThenBy(x => x.Category) to sort the remaining offers by Category name..?

Comment: I'm hesitant to rely upon the ordering of false and true and that other developers would understand it. I'm inclined to make my intent absolutely clear, such as `.OrderBy(x => x.Category == "Corporate" ? 0 : 1)`.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft the order of everything else will be undefined (if OrderBy uses an unstable sort, which I think it does).

Comment: Ah I see, I was misunderstanding the boolean argument

Answer (score 21):

The [C# Language Specification 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) does not specify a byte representation for the `true` and `false` values. Therefore, it is better to not rely on the assumption that `true` is represented by `1`. Also, the result of sorting by the Boolean expression `x.Category == "Corporate"` is not obvious, as `true` could be represented by a negative value as well. Therefore, I use a ternary operator to explicitly specify a sort value:

```
Offers = Offers
    .OrderBy(x => x.Category == "Corporate" ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Category)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Date) // or what ever
    .ToList();
```