# LinQ OrderBy specific element in sublist

Tags: linq, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I have a Category class

```
public class Category
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public Translation[] Translations { get; set; }
}
```

and a Translation class

```
public  class Translation
{
   public string Locale { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a List of Categories `List<Category>` that is populated with category objects. I want to order my `unorderedCategoryList` alphabetically by the **Name** field  in `Translation` based on specified **Locale**.

So for example I have 3 categories:

```
{1, ["EN","aaa"], ["RU","zzz"]}

{2, ["EN","ccc"], ["RU","eee"]}

{3, ["EN","bbb"], ["RU","aaa"]}
```

Ordering them with specified locale `EN` would result in a list ordered like this:

```
{1, ["EN","aaa"], ["RU","zzz"]}
{3, ["EN","bbb"], ["RU","aaa"]}
{2, ["EN","ccc"], ["RU","eee"]}
```

and by `RU` like this:

```
{3, ["EN","bbb"], ["RU","aaa"]}
{2, ["EN","ccc"], ["RU","eee"]}
{1, ["EN","aaa"], ["RU","zzz"]}
```

This line of code is as far as I got but it doesn't seem to work :

```
var sortedList = unorderedCategoryList.OrderBy(go => go.Translations.Where(t => t.Locale == "EN").Select(t => t.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Custom Comparer for Category Type as follows.

```
public class CategoryComparer : IComparer<Category>
{
    private string _locale;
    public CategoryComparer(string locale)
    {
        _locale = locale;
    }
    public int Compare(Category x, Category y)
    {
        var orderedX = x.Translations.Where(c=>c.Locale.Equals(_locale)).OrderBy(c=>c.Name);
        var orderedY = y.Translations.Where(c=>c.Locale.Equals(_locale)).OrderBy(c=>c.Name);
        return orderedX.First().Name.CompareTo(orderedY.First().Name);
    }
}
```

Now you could sort as

```
var sortByKey = "EN";
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(x=>x,new CategoryComparer(sortByKey));
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xC4R5H)

Comment: Your answer seems easiest to understand and cleanest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var sortedList = unorderedCategoryList
                    .OrderBy(go => go.Translations.OrderByDescending(t => t.Name == "EN")).ToList();
```

Unverified but I pulled sources from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436857/sort-a-list-so-a-specific-value-ends-up-on-top?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617596/how-do-i-sort-a-collection-with-child-property)