# Order by multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have list which I want to order by like this

- First by "ab"
- Then by alphabetical order inside the list by "ab"
- Then by "cd"
- Then by alphabetical order inside the list by "cd"
- Then by "ef"
- Then by alphabetical order inside the list by "ef"

and then the rest by alphabetical order

I have this linq query

```
var groups =  profileModel.Groups.
OrderByDescending(i => i.FullName.ToLower().Contains("ab")).
ThenByDescending(i => i.FullName.ToLower().Contains("cd")).
ThenByDescending(i => i.FullName.ToLower().Contains("ef"));
```

How should I extend this one? Do I have to use group by?

Comment: You notice that you have multiple `First by`? Provide a Sample

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728319/linq-orderby-against-specific-values

Comment: Are you doing this on IQueriable(EF to SQL) or in memory IEnumerable

Comment: So how about a FullName that is "abcdef" ?

Comment: Note: "then by"  means "then another sort"; it isn't talking about *vertical partitions*; are you trying to describe vertical partitions? You can *implement* that by multiple sorts, but it is... very odd

Comment: @Marc : I think he just wants a sort of 'order by priority'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want this, then no need to use `GroupBy`:

```
var groupOrders = new List<string> { "ab", "cd", "ef" };

var resultList = profileModel.Groups
    .Select(x => new { ModelGroup = x, First2Letter = x.FullName.Substring(Math.Min(2, x.FullName.Length)) })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.ModelGroup,
        x.First2Letter,
        Index = groupOrders.FindIndex(s => s.Equals(x.First2Letter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Index >= 0) // first all known groups
    .ThenBy(x => x.Index)
    .ThenBy(x => x.ModelGroup.FullName)
    .Select(x => x.ModelGroup)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: maybe replace Equals with Contains ?

Comment: @Florian: No, `s` is the string in the list and `First2Letter` are the first two letters of each `FullName`.

Comment: Right, your solution is different from what I had in mind, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem correctly, this will order items based on what they contain. should work in EF as well.

```
var orderItems = from item in profileModel.Groups
                 let name = item.FullName.ToLower()
                 orderby (name.Contains("ab") ? 1 : 0) + (name.Contains("cd") ? 0.1 : 0) + (name.Contains("ef") ? 0.01 : 0) descending
                 select item;
```

EDIT 
After rereading the problem this might be the right solution

```
var orderItems = from item in profileModel.Groups
                 let name = item.FullName.ToLower()
                 let order = name.Contains("ab") ? 3 : name.Contains("cd") ? 2 : name.Contains("ef") ? 1 : 0
                 orderby order descending, item.FullName
                 select item;
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom ordering, you can assign a value to each compare condition and OrderByDescending will order by that. Something like this..

```
            lstModel = profileModel.Groups.OrderByDescending(m => m.FullName.ToLower().Contains("ab") ? 3 :
            m.FullName.ToLower().Contains("cd") ? 2 :
            m.FullName.ToLower().Contains("ef") ? 1 : 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you might have more or different level1 values to test, you may want a generic version.

Using a convenient extension method `FirstOrDefault` that takes the default value to return

```
public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, bool> test, T defval) => src.Where(aT => test(aT)).DefaultIfEmpty(defval).First();
```

You can create an array of first level values in order, and sort first on that, then alphabetically:

```
var level1 = new[] { "ab", "cd", "ef" };

var ans = groups.OrderBy(i => level1.Select((op, n) => (op, n))
                                    .FirstOrDefault(opn => i.FullName.Contains(opn.op),
                                                    (op: String.Empty, n: level1.Length)).n)
                .ThenBy(i => i.FullName);
```