# How to filter String array with integer array with LINQ by index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
String[] columnList = new String[]{"column1","column2","column3","column4","column5","column6","column7","column8","column9","column10","column11","column12" };

Int[] fList = new Int[] { 1,3,5,10,12 };
```

I want output like this:

```
column1,column3,column5,column10,column12
```

Comment: This question might help you. It is a bit different, but should be similar other than some string formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728319/linq-orderby-against-specific-values

Comment: This sounds like homework. You sould at least shown an attempt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this is not homework!  This will do the trick:

```
var joined = from column in columnList.Select((x, i) => new {Index = i + 1, Column = x} )
             join index in fList on column.Index equals index
             select column.Column;
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", joined));

// output
// column1,column3,column5,column10,column12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `String.Join` with `Select`

```
string result = string.Join(",", fList.Select(n => columnList[n-1]));
```

Obviously you need to ensure that the index exists. If you dont know that you could use `ElementAtOrDefault(n-1)` instead of `[n-1]`.

Comment: This method works. Thanks a Lot. 2 hours struggle.